# When adding existing user control I get "already contains" and "already defines" error

Tags: c#

I'm using a C# text book called "Head First C#" and I'm working on the hive simulator, where you import the three BeeControl elements from another project. They work fine in the other project but as soon as I rebuild the solution after importing to the new project and changing the namespace, as per the instructions, I get the following three errors that have me stumped...Keeping in mind that the elements that throw "already contain" and "already defined" errors coexisted peacefully in the project from which they came.

EDIT: I'm adding clarifying code - making it a much longer post. Hope it helps! My first thought is to just remove all the duplications but, again, it worked fin in the project from which it was imported and the book doesn't say anything about it so I don't want to mess up my lesson down the road.

Thanks again for any help!

> **Error 1** The type 'Hive_Simulator.BeeControl' already contains a
>   definition for 'components' C:\Users[...]\Hive
>   Simulator\BeeControl.designer.cs 8 50 Hive Simulator

```
 From BeeControl.designer.cs:
 partial class BeeControl
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
}

From BeeControl.cs:
public partial class BeeControl : UserControl

{
    private Timer AnimationTimer;
    private IContainer components;
}
```

> **Error 2** Type
>   'Hive_Simulator.BeeControl' already defines a member called
>   'InitializeComponent' with the same parameter types
>   C:\Users[...]\Hive Simulator\BeeControl.designer.cs 29 22 Hive
>   Simulator

```
From BeeControl.designer.cs:
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.AnimationTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // timer1
        // 
        this.AnimationTimer.Enabled = true;
        this.AnimationTimer.Interval = 150;
        this.AnimationTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        // 
        // BeeControl
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Name = "BeeControl";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

From BeeControl.cs:
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.AnimationTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // AnimationTimer
        // 
        this.AnimationTimer.Enabled = true;
        this.AnimationTimer.Interval = 150;
        this.AnimationTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.AnimationTimer_Tick);
        // 
        // BeeControl
        // 
        this.Name = "BeeControl";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```

> **Error 3** The type 'Hive_Simulator.BeeControl' already
>   contains a definition for 'AnimationTimer' C:\Users[...]\Hive
>   Simulator\BeeControl.designer.cs 52 44 Hive Simulator

```
From BeeControl.designer.cs:
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer AnimationTimer;

From BeeControl.cs:
private Timer AnimationTimer;
```

Comment: Are there any partial classes involved here? Are you importing the same class definition more than once?

Comment: Are you copy pasting the code from the form class to the new project? You should create an empty project and create new class file. Paste the code in that file.

Comment: I'm guessing from the fact that you have a .designer.cs that you are using partial classes. Check whether you are in fact defining "components" in more than one place. Perhaps you imported a designer class and VS made another one or something... Without more details though its all just guesswork...

Comment: Did you change the namespace as indicated in the grey box on page 287?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Ok, so yes partial classes are involved and no I'm not importing anything more than once. No, I'm not copy pasting the code, I'm importing by "add existing item". And yes, "components" is indeed defined in two places (in slightly different ways) but the IDE did this itself and, again, it worked fine before being transferred to another project even though both the .cs and .designer.cs files peacefully coexisted before with the dual declarations/definitions. I will perhaps post some clarifying code snippets later tonight or tomorrow if someone doesn't hit the nail on the head. Thanks BTW...

Comment: Clarifying code is never a bad idea... Else, all we can do is have a shot in the dark.

Comment: So with the clarifying code added in, I don't know if I've scared people off? I'm hoping this is a relatively easy thing to fix, but now I'm wondering if I should just build out the BeeControl class in my original project and hope that doesn't mess up the flow of the lesson...